# SuperSet configuration with SSL DRUID

Tags: https, apache-superset, druid

I am newbie on superset and trying to configure DRUID .. successfully start superset and saw the examples .. but when I tried to connect druid (it has only https connectionavailable for me ) .. I got error message when I tried to

```
[root@XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXbin]# superset refresh_druid
2018-02-21 23:08:05,618:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): my.dnsname.com
Error while processing cluster 'druid'
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x02P',))
```

It is trying to connect HTTP. How can I make sure it is trying to connect HTTPS?

Comment: What version of Superset are you using?